# Jetpack Compose TextField in LazyColumn

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, focus

I'd like to not show "First item" when TextField is in focus. However refresh make TextField to loose focus.

```
    var addFirstItem by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    LazyColumn {
        if (addFirstItem) {
            item {
                Text(
                    text = "First item",
                    Modifier
                        .background(Color.Red)
                        .height(100.dp)
                )
            }
        }

        item {
            TextField(value = "Second Item",
                onValueChange = {},
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color.Blue)
                    .height(100.dp)
                    .onFocusChanged { focusState ->
                        addFirstItem = !focusState.isFocused
                    }
            )
        }
    }
```

When I operate on visibility of first item it works instead this if:
`if (addFirstItem)`

But if I had a lot of items I'd prefer not load all.

Comment: Try using an explicit `key` in your `item` calls